# When setup is removed from windows installer cache?

Tags: windows-installer, setup, group-policy

I observe strange behavior on several notebooks. All of them have application installed as an MSI package, through GPO deployment, from the network share. But when this network share is inaccessible, application cannot be uninstalled or upgraded, complaining about missing source.

As far as I know, windows installer caches setups in `c:\windows\installer` folder just for such cases, so that application could be uninstalled even if original setup is gone.

Under what conditions and when setup could be automatically removed from the installer cache? Is there any setting that may prevent setup from being cached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

[ResolveSource Requires Source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/resolvesource-requires-source/)

The cache found in C:\windows\installer is not meant to be a full cache.  It's a minimal MSI that's been stripped of it's embedded cabs ( if it was a compressed build ).

There is a second mechanism for caching in that if the cached MSI is not found or the cached MSI doesn't have the storage (Cabs)  then it'll use a source list resolution process.  Typically this is the location the MSI was installed from.   Or a location the MSI was extracted to (cached) by a setup.exe.   Also if you have tools like Microsoft Systems Center Configuration Manager  it has a mechanism of caching the packages and calling MSI API's to inform the service of the locations.

You always want the MSI cached in c:\windows\installer and there is no mechanism to enable or disable this.